# How to create a dataframe from a python dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

new_dict = {'mid': ['1', '2'], 'type': ['a', 'b']}

df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict.items(), columns=list(new_dict), index=None)

print(df)
```

This print out as:

```
mid    type
0   mid  [1, 2]
1  type  [a, b]
```

But I hope it prints out as:

```
mid    type
1       a
2       b
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--Edit : As @DeepSpace pointed out in the comments to my answer, your mistake was in passing the new_dict.items() function result as the data rather than just the dict itself.

Keeping it simple, if you just do this, without needing to specify the columns and index arguments, it works:

```
new_dict = {"mid":["1","2"], "type":["a", "b"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
print(df)
```

This is the result, which I think is what you want:

```
  mid type
0   1    a
1   2    b
```

And here it is with specifying something for columns and index:
new_dict = {"mid":["1","2"], "type":["a", "b"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict, columns=list(new_dict), index=None)
print(df)

output:

```
  mid type
0   1    a
1   2    b
```

And, if you were trying to print the Dataframe without showing the index, which seems to be your desired output, you can do this:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))

mid type
  1    a
  2    b
```

Comment: *"you passed the dict as the value for the column argument to the DataFrame method"* Not really. OP passed a list of tuples to the data argument. Otherwise they would have got an exception that says the `columns` argument got multiple values.

Comment: Also, `[k for k in new_dict.keys()]` is **exactly** the same as `list(new_dict)` that OP used.

Comment: The only issue in OP's code is that they did `pd.DataFrame(new_dict.items(), ...` instead of just `pd.DataFrame(new_dict, ...`

Comment: Thanks for those comments DeepSpace.  You are right.  I realized the same as I was refining my answer.  I realized that casting the dict to a list just makes a list of the keys, which would be the column names he wanted to use.  I also see that they used the .items property of the dict, which I missed the first time around, so yeah - that is the problem.